# How to call resource file message from javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have resource file in English and japans, so is my website turn to japans language need to display japans messages same as English, so need to display messages dynamically in java script.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? ASP.NET allows you to create headless (no UI) APIs, and web applications with WebForms, Razor, etc., or you use something like Angular which could be applied through Razor or by communicating with API methods using AJAX. What is the resource file you mention? Is that an actual .NET resource, or is it something in Javascript?

Comment: I am using this in normal c# asp.net web form, like at server end we declared label text that text value I have to call in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can add resources.resx to your project and write  the function below in a common controller .

```
#if !DEBUG
        [OutputCache(Duration = 24 * 60 * 60)]
#endif
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResourcesForJavascript()
        {
            try
            {
                var resourceSet = JsResources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
                var resourceDictionary = resourceSet
                                .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key.ToString(), entry => entry.Value.ToString());
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceDictionary);
                var javaScript = $"window.Resources = window.Resources || {{}}; window.Resources.resources = {json};";
                return JavaScript(javaScript);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WebExceptionHelper.FillModelStateOrTempDataWithExceptionMessages(ex, ModelState, TempData);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And call it as follows in the _Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("ResourcesForJavascript", "CommonActions")"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use resource file message, you need to inject Locatization on related view.
Example: assume you have a view with the name abc.cshtml and you want to show an alert message from resource file when a button is clicked

View: abc.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

in script section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callOnButtonClick(){
alert('@Localizer["Hello message from resource"]');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not in mvc, Want solution for c# asp.net.

Comment: @pooja ASP.NET is MVC, it is Web Forms, it is WebAPI. Maybe you only uae it in one form, but there are many others as you can see. That's why it's important for you to specify what form of ASP.NET you're using, especially when WebForms is not the most common way people work with it.

Comment: @pooja please specify which one is you are using among Asp.net Webforms, MVC, Razor pages, Core MVC?

Comment: I am using aps.net web form in vb and c#.